# Is it possible to fix this? ft-rockey.rules:1

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10

Kubuntu 15.10 - Single OS - Desktop

```
Emergency Mode - journalctl -xb read out - red text
```

Can I fix this to get my Kubuntu back up and running?

```
unknown key 'BUS' in /etc/udev/rules.d/ft-rockey.rules:1
invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/ft-rockey.rules:1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved -

rm -rdfv /etc/udev/rules.d/ft-rockey.rules

I have no idea what rockey was, but i do know that with mr rockey gone Im back up and running again without emergency mode - kudos to askubuntu and internet searches!!